# Smallest square in which other squares fit

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

What is the sidelength of the smallest square in which one can fit $n$ non-overlapping squares of sidelengths $1,2,3,4,...,n$ ?

And what is the sidelength of the smallest cube in which one can fit $n$ non-intersecting cubes of sidelengths $1,2,3,4,...,n$ ?

All squares/cubes have all sides paralell, no rotation

Comment: For squares, there is information at http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_12_01_03.html  The series is http://oeis.org/A005842.  I didn't find a series for cubes and my Google search turned up travel tips on packing.

Comment: I'll accept asymptotics

Comment: The sum of the squares up to $n^2$ is  $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, so when $n$ gets very large I would expect them to pack into about the square root of that, $\sqrt{n^3/6}$.  Similarly for cubes, the volume is $n^2(n+1)^2/4$ and I would expect the cube root of that.  This is just because you have lots of little pieces, so shouldn't have to waste that much space, no better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 180 dollars, you can get a [37 squares solution](http://www.gamepuzzles.com/37square.htm)  and there is some [discussion of cubes](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/13Sep04.html) and here's a discussion of [70 squares](http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/misc/squares.html).